# Confused about $L^\infty$ norm

Tags: measure-theory

Is the following statement true?

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, and $u:U\to \mathbb{R}$ be non-negative. Then

$$\| u \|_{L^\infty}\leq u(x)$$ for all $x\in U.$

Answer (score 1):

No, you have 
$$
\|u\|_{L_{\infty}}=\mathrm{ess\ sup}_{x\in U} |u(x)|
$$
and thus
$$
u(x)\leq \|u\|_{L_\infty}
$$
for almost all $x\in U$, i.e. for all $x$ except for some subset of measure $0$.

Comment: "ess" stands for "essential" and is pretty international, too. It means that you can "leave out" any subset of Lebesgue measure zero when taking the supremum. Take e.g. $u(x)=0$ for $x\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ and $u(x)=1$ $x\in\mathbb Q$. Then $\mathrm{sup}_{x\in\mathbb R} u(x)=1$ but $\mathrm{ess\ sup}_{x\in\mathbb R} u(x)=0$. (See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_supremum)

Comment: My bad! =) ${}{}$.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's backwards. The definition of the infinity norm is that $\|u\|_{L^{\infty}}$ is the smallest $\alpha \in [0, \infty]$ such that

$$|u(x)| \le \alpha$$

for almost every $x$.